# python __init__ assignment with operator 'or'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import operator

class ClassTupleMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassTupleMeta, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for n, name in enumerate(cls._fields):
            setattr(cls, name, property(operator.itemgetter(n)))

class ClassTuple(tuple):
    _fields = []
    __metaclass__ = ClassTupleMeta
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if (len(args) != len(cls._fields)):
            raise ValueError('{} arguments required',format(len(cls._fields)))
        return super(ClassTuple, cls).__new__(cls, args)

class CommonConstExam(ClassTuple):
    _fields = ['long_run_50', 'long_run_800', 'long_run_1000']

    def __init__(self, *arg):
        super(CommonConstExam, self).__init__()
        #setattr(self, 'long_run', self.long_run_50 or self.long_run_800 or self.long_run_1000)
```

See code above, for the last line, there's always one of long_run_50, self.long_run_800, self.long_run_1000 that has an non-None value, and I try to assign the non-None value to long_run, but it is always assigned the value of long_run_50, whether it is None or not. And also, if I rewrite it as if-else clauses, it is assigned the value in first if clause. Does anybody know how to tackle this problem? I really want to use only one variable(long_run), which can extremely simplify the following code.

Comment: If you want `self.long_run_1000` to take precedence over the other values, you need to list it first.  `or` evaluates to the first truthy value it sees.

Comment: The same problem will happen that long_run will be always assigned long_run_1000.

Comment: Tuple values must be set via `__new__`, not `__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your problem is this line:

```
setattr(self, 'long_run', self.long_run_50 or self.long_run_800 or self.long_run_1000)
```

The trouble with `or`-expressions like this is that they sometimes do things you didn't mean: `0` and `""`, both of which might be legal and interesting values, both count as `False`. The converse is also true. Suppose, for example, that `long_run_50` has the string value `"None"`. That might be very hard to see. Especially as it is probably the result of a bug elsewhere, and so unexpected.

Try using an inline `if`-expression that specifies exactly what you mean, for example

```
setattr(self, 'long_run',
        self.long_run_50 if self.long_run_50 is not None 
        else 
        self.long_run_800 if self.long_run_800 is not None
        else 
        self.long_run_1000 if self.long_run_1000 is not None
        else "Nyah-nyah-nyah")
```

I do wonder why you are using `setattr()` when it could, as far as I can see, just as well be

```
self.long_run = (  ...etc... )
```

There are at least three good reasons why you might be doing that, but I do have to ask.